# Possible Number of Repetation of a Submatrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colorings, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

**Notation:**
$H$  is the  adjacency matrix of graph $H'$ respectively. $H_k$ is the  block or sub-matrix of matrix $H$. The adjacency matrix of graph $H_k \cup  H_e$ (subgraphs of $H'$) is $M_{(k,e)}$ where   $M_{(k,e)} =\left( \begin{array}{ccc} H_e & R_{k,e} \\ R_{k,e}^{T} & H_k\\ \end{array} \right) $,  where, $R_{k,e}$ is the non symmetric sub-matrix of adjacency matrix $H$.  Here, $R_{k,e}$ represents  edges  between $H_k,  H_e$.   The matrix $H$ looks like-
$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
H_{(x)} & R_{(x, x-1)} & R_{(x,x-2)} & \dots & \dots & R_{(x,1)} \\
R_{(x,x-1)^{T}} & H_{(x-1)} & R_{(x-1,x-2)} & \dots & \dots & R_{(x-1,1)} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
R_{(x,1)^{T}} & R_{(x-1,1)^{T}} & R_{(x-2,1)^{T}} & \dots & \dots &H_{1} \end{bmatrix}$$.

Each $M_{k,e}$ can have exactly $6$ vertices, $3$ vertices in $H_k$ and $3$ vertices in $H_e$.

**Fact:**
$R_{k,e}$ is a non-symmetric matrix of dimension $3 \times 3$ .
It is clear that each distinct $R_{k,e}$ can appear maximum $b$ times where $b \leq n^{9}$, since there are maximum $n^{3}$ different possible $H_k$  and $n^{3}$ different possible $H_e$ .

**Problem:** Is there any result against the following statement-

Each distinct $R_{k,e}$ can appear maximum $\sqrt b \leq n^{3}$ times for different pair of $H_k, H_e$.

I am assuming  the statement is correct.

**Context:** This is related to  "individualization" of $k$ vertices of a graph. The problem is related to my earlier query [Graph Coloring: Two adjacent vertices share same color](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/241486/graph-coloring-two-adjacent-vertices-share-same-color).

Comment: This question has received only very little attention so far -- maybe you wish to edit.

Comment: @StefanKohl , thnks for ur attention and advice but am not going to do anything with this post, actually am thinking how to delete my account of MOSE... tnx though.